# generating irregular mesh of a cube

Tags: matlab, mesh, cubes

I want to generate a mesh for solving the Laplace equation on using FEM. I want to solve it on a cube and I would like to mesh the cube using tetrahedra. Is there a way to do this in MATLAB using unstructured meshes, i.e. that I can choose if the density if elements should be higher in a specific region?

Comment: I work with FEM and Matlab, and generally use out-of matlab software for meshing.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Any recommendations?

Comment: @knedlsepp I get error!.

Comment: @BillyJean I recommend the `iso2mesh` package, else, you can go for `distmesh` or `Netgen`, but this last one has no Matlab interface.

Comment: Posting some advertisement for my FEM-Laplace-solver for arbitrary dimensions [p1afem-nD](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47469-p1afem-nd): Includes adaptive mesh refinement, so you can have a finer mesh in some specific area if you want, but even better: an h-adaptive algorithm, which automatically refines in the region where the residual is large, so there is no need for you to manually refine the mesh, just let the algorithm do the work. ;-)